# C++ Как определить шаблонный конструктор копирования в pull allocator?

Tags: c++, память, шаблоны-с++

Пишу свой `pull allocator`, но возникла проблема c шаблонным конструктором копирования.

```
template<class T>
class PoolAllocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = size_t;

    pointer allocate(size_type count) const {
        T* ret = pool + *curPos;
        *curPos += count;
        return ret;
    }
    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type count) const {
    }

    PoolAllocator() {
        pool = reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * 100'000));
        counter = new size_t(1);
        curPos = new size_t(0);
    }
    PoolAllocator(const PoolAllocator<T>& another) {
        this->pool = another.pool;
        this->counter = another.counter;
        ++(this->counter);
        this->curPos = another.curPos;
    }
    ~PoolAllocator() {
        --(*counter);
        if (*counter == 0) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < *curPos; ++i) {
                (pool + i)->~T();
            }
            ::operator delete(pool);
            delete counter;
            delete curPos;
        }
    }

    template <class U>
    PoolAllocator(const PoolAllocator<U>& another) {
        // Что тут нужно написать?
    }
    

private:
    T* pool;
    size_t* counter;
    size_t* curPos;
};
```

Мне не понятно как его определить. Я не могу просто скопировать все указатели, потому что тип данных пула разный(`T*`). К тому же я не могу обратиться к private переменным через `another`. Как быть, что делать?

Comment: Запретите его вызов посредством `= delete`. Кроме того, тип данных в этом объвлении у `another` будет тот же самый. А копировать указатели не можете из-за того, что ими владеет другой объект.

Comment: @user7860670 1) у меня счетчик для указателей стоит. 2) Что значит удалить его? Он мне нужен для того чтобы std контейнеры его могли использовать. 3) Тип `another` будет не тот же самый. Я не про обычный конструктор копирования говорю, а про шаблонный, который в самом низу находится)

Comment: 1) Если хотите разделять владение, то делайте в этом аллокаторе `shered_ptr` на реальный аллокатор, почти PIMPL 2) обычный конструктор копирования тогда будет работать 3) да, второй я не заметил, но это тоже может быть решено через PIMPL, т.е. когда тип нижележащего аллокатора не шаблонный

Comment: @Lofectr, вообще то распределителям не нужно хранить указатели.  Для конкретного типа выделяют участок памяти в заданном количестве (который передается в  функция_член allocate) и удаляют(deallocate ) для заданного указателя  .  Если хотите хранить размер, то просто храните его как переменную. Но  это не будет оправдан, потому что  контейнеры каждый раз не создают новый распределитель,  для каждого изменения  размера Таким образом ваш шаблонный конструктор  останется с пустым телом.  И еще полезно определить шаблонную структуру rebind где определите псевдоним other.

Comment: @user7860670 Да, у меня получилось сделать указатель void*, но чтобы из another(шаблонного) скопировать указатели в this мне пришлось сделать поля публичными. Почему у меня нет доступа к членам another? И как красиво решить это?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну общий пул это хорошая идея) А на счет rebind не понял вас. Контейнеры же обращаются через allocator_traits, который сам определяет rebind

Comment: Чтобы был доступ к приватным полям другие шаблоны следует объявить как `template<typename TT> friend
class PoolAllocator;`

Comment: @Lofectr,  в принципе свойства определенного распределителя (allocator_traits) должны специализироваться конкретным распределителем, которому нужна  rebind, как и все другие необходимые функции, потому что   свойства распределителя  используются  в распределителях, а в контейнерах используются  сами распределители

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если бы контейнеры не использовали бы allocator_traits, то мой аллокатор не работал бы с std::list, а он работает. Ну кстати к слову, он не работает с вектором почему-то(RE)

Comment: все зависит от контейнера и от реализации, поэтому на все случаи нужно иметь все функции члены.